# Alternate method of BeanInfo creation?

Tags: java, spring, java-8, java-7

I recently moved my spring application from java 1.6 to java 1.8. This has caused the spring bootstrapping to take an order of magnitude longer (20s before, 4mins now). Tracing the cause has led me to the `CachedIntrospectionResults` class, which is created for every bean. When created it calls,

```
beanInfo = (shouldIntrospectorIgnoreBeaninfoClasses ?
                        Introspector.getBeanInfo(beanClass, Introspector.IGNORE_ALL_BEANINFO) :
                        Introspector.getBeanInfo(beanClass));
```

Introspector then creates the bean info, in java **1.6**, it calls

```
 private BeanDescriptor getTargetBeanDescriptor() {
    // Use explicit info, if available,
    if (explicitBeanInfo != null) {
        BeanDescriptor bd = explicitBeanInfo.getBeanDescriptor();
        if (bd != null) {
            return (bd);
        }
    }
    // OK, fabricate a default BeanDescriptor.
    return new BeanDescriptor(this.beanClass);
}
```

However in java **1.8** it now calls,

```
private BeanDescriptor getTargetBeanDescriptor() {
    // Use explicit info, if available,
    if (explicitBeanInfo != null) {
        BeanDescriptor bd = explicitBeanInfo.getBeanDescriptor();
        if (bd != null) {
            return (bd);
        }
    }
    // OK, fabricate a default BeanDescriptor.
    return new BeanDescriptor(this.beanClass, findCustomizerClass(this.beanClass));
}
private static Class<?> findCustomizerClass(Class<?> type) {
    String name = type.getName() + "Customizer";
    try {
        type = ClassFinder.findClass(name, type.getClassLoader());
        // Each customizer should inherit java.awt.Component and implement java.beans.Customizer
        // according to the section 9.3 of JavaBeans&trade; specification
        if (Component.class.isAssignableFrom(type) && Customizer.class.isAssignableFrom(type)) {
            return type;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exception) {
        // ignore any exceptions
    }
    return null;
}
```

This method as far as I can see was added with java 1.7, and since I don't define any customizer classes, it searches my full classpath then throws an exception which ends up taking a few hundred ms. The result being that each bean takes ~500ms to init. A huge hit to startup time.

I am now trying to find a way to work around this problem,

The spring documentation says to implement a BeanInfoFactory in order to customize the beanInfo creation. But I can't find anywhere that says how to actaually create BeanInfo for a provided class.

How would I actually do that? Introspector uses a bunch of private constructors to build it up so I can't really follow it, and simply returning an empty BeanInfo blows spring up. What does spring actually want with the beaninfo?

Any ideas?

Comment: Related: https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-9014

Comment: @skaffman Thank you for the link, I was already aware of it and unfortunately it deals with a very different code path than the issue I am seeing. The Introspection is very fast for finding the existing bean. It always searches for a non existent `Customizer` bean as well, which is ridiculously slow. OT: I find it nuts that they thought it was a good idea to search the cp for a bean that 99.9% of the time doesn't exist, and then go ahead and use an Exception as the main code path. And they don't even cache it! Every repeated call re-searches the cp for the non-existent bean. Every time. Nuts.

Answer (score 0):

Normally, when you provide an explicit `BeanInfo`, the Introspector will gather information automatically whenever the explicit `BeanInfo` returns `null`. So there should be no problem providing an empty `BeanInfo` that only returns a non-`null` `BeanDescriptor` to prohibit the automatic `Customizer` search.

For example:

```
import java.beans.*;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class BeanInfoTest {
    public static void main(String... arg) throws IntrospectionException {
        BeanInfo bi=Introspector.getBeanInfo(TheComponent.class, Object.class);
        System.out.println("properties: ");
        Stream.of(bi.getPropertyDescriptors())
              .map(p->p.getPropertyType().getSimpleName()+' '+p.getName())
              .forEach(System.out::println);
    }
    public static class TheComponent {
        String foo;
        int bar;
        public String getFoo() {
            return foo;
        }
        public void setFoo(String foo) {
            this.foo = foo;
        }
        public int getBar() {
            return bar;
        }
        public void setBar(int bar) {
            this.bar = bar;
        }
    }
    public static class TheComponentBeanInfo extends SimpleBeanInfo {

        /** Overridden to prevent the automated search for a Customizer */
        @Override
        public BeanDescriptor getBeanDescriptor() {
            System.out.println("Providing my explicit BeanDescriptor");
            return new BeanDescriptor(TheComponent.class);
        }
    }
}
```

will print

```
Providing my explicit BeanDescriptor
properties: 
int bar
String foo
```

So it found the properties using automated search while using the explicit `BeanDescriptor`.

Comment: Thanks for the help, if I understand you correctly, in order for spring to work the same way as it did in java 1.6, I need to create a boilerplate BeanInfo class for all my(~2000) beans? That seems insane. When I mentioned creating BeanInfo, i was referring to the [BeanInfoFactory](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/BeanInfoFactory.html). Is there no other way around this?